# Como centralizar horizontalmente na tela um item de uma recyclerview (horizontal)?

Tags: java, android, carousel, horizontal

O que eu quero é o seguinte resultado:

[image]

[image]

Sempre que o usuário passar para o item seguinte ou anterior, ele será centralizado na tela, assim como funciona se eu usasse o Carousel. Tentei algumas libs de carousel só que elas só permitiam adicionar textos/imagens, sendo que eu preciso colocar um layout dentro com alguns editTexts e buttons que, posteriormente, serão recuperados seus respectivos valores.

Answer (score 0):

Se você for usar botões para gerenciar a navegação você pode usar este comando:

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
```

que irá centralizar na recycler view a posição passada no construtor.

Espero que ajude.

Answer (score 0):

Se algum outro desenvolvedor precisar dessa resposta atualmente:

```
LinearSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(R.id.seu_recycler_view)
```

Adiciona esse techo de código. (kotlin)